# Nullpointer exception initiliazing associates of a hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, tomcat7

Hi I have a entity model that has a composite key and associated objects. Following is the hbm.xml for it

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.mytrits.admin.Mtmdmsgqna" table="mtmdmsgqna" catalog="mtmdadmin">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.mytrits.admin.MtmdmsgqnaId">
        <key-property name="messageId" type="int">
            <column name="MessageId" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="qserialNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="QSerialNo" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="qsenderId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="QSenderID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="qtext" type="string">
            <column name="QText" length="1000" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="aserialNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ASerialNo" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="asenderId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ASenderID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="atext" type="string">
            <column name="AText" length="1000" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="mtmduser" class="com.mytrits.admin.Mtmduser" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="QSenderID" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="mtmdmessages" class="com.mytrits.admin.Mtmdmessages" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="MessageId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

I am fetching a List using a namedQuery, below is the query

```
<query name="getQNAforMsg">
    <![CDATA[from Mtmdmsgqna where messageId = :msgId order by qserialNo, aserialNo]]>
</query>
```

in my managed bean i am trying to iterate thru the list but get NullPointerException. The List of entities has size() > 0, but when I tried to access the object (with in the same session), it fails and gives me a NullPointerException. The initial object fetched fro the list is itself NULL. Below is my bean code

```
private void buildQATree() {
    try {
        MtmdmsgqnaHome qnasHome = new MtmdmsgqnaHome();
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
        qnaList = qnasHome.findQNAbyMsg(messageId.intValue());
        Iterator it = qnaList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Mtmdmsgqna mqna = (Mtmdmsgqna) it.next();
            mqna.getId().getMessageId();
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (HibernateUtil.isTransactionActive()) HibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
        log.error("Exception fetching Entity Types"+ex);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error Getting Message Detail", "Error Getting Message Detail"));          
    }               
}
```

I have a similar case in another part of the project, but have no issues with similar code there. I am not sure what is the issue here. I have also tried the following methods to iterate, but get the same problem.

```
/*          
        for (Mtmdmsgqna mqna : qnaList) {
            Hibernate.initialize(mqna);
            Hibernate.initialize(mqna.getId());
            Hibernate.initialize(mqna.getMtmduser());
        }
```

*/

```
/*
        for (int i = 0; i < qnaList.size(); i++) {
            Hibernate.initialize(qnaList.get(i));
            Hibernate.initialize(qnaList.get(i).getId());
            Hibernate.initialize(qnaList.get(i).getMtmduser());
        }
```

*/

I suspect that, since the composite key is a seperate class in itself, it is not fetched (as Lazy='true') And since I do not have any other elements other than the many-to-ones, nothing is eagerly fetched. So even thou there is data in DB, the object is null. Since the main entity object itself is null, I am not able to navigate further thru the associated objects for initialization. I suspect I will have to fetch the composite-id data eagerly atleast. I am novice to Hibernate and couldn't find a way to set lazy-eager attribute on composite-key in the hbm file. Let me know if that is possible. Also let me know if anything else could be a issue. Any help will be great.